# Pb in while with equal

Tags: python, while-loop, equality

Has someone an explication of the following pb ?

In the following example, A must be different than sign but in the while loop, A is equal to sign.

The solution I found is to put A = str(sign).

```
sign =range(10)
i=0
while i<10:
    print i
    A = sign
    sign.remove(i)
    print A
    print sign
    i=i+1


0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
...
```

Comment: Old farts like me think Pb means lead. Can you use real words please?

Comment: I don't know what Pb means either, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are mutable. 
this will illustrate why `A` and `sign` are same.

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
140597647738424
>>> id(a)
140597647738424
>>> a.remove(1)
>>> b
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

try slicing if you wan changes in `A` and `sign`

so that

```
>>>a = range(10)
>>>b = a[:]

>>> id(b)
140597646666280
>>> id(a)
140597646666496
```

Comment: Is is possible to make an immutable copy ?

Comment: @alexis0587 immutable copy of what?

Comment: @alexis0587, no - lists are always mutable. It's possible to make a copy though

Comment: @gnibbler: I achived to do a copy with a = list(b) :) Thank you

Comment: @alexis0587 a = list(b) is a right way but more pythonic way is using slicing. so a = b[:].